# Java 9 dependency issues regarding serviceloader

Tags: java, reflection, dependencies, java-9, serviceloader

I have a question about how the serviceloader changed in Java 9 based on this scenario

---

### Scenario

Project `gert` Class `Main`

```
package gert;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Main { 
    static public void test() throws JAXBException {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("<Classes RUNTIME_INCLUDE_JARS=\"\"><Class></Class></Classes>".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassesDef.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
    }
}
```

Project `gert` Class `ClassesDef`

```
package gert;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Classes")
public class ClassesDef {
    @XmlAttribute(name="RUNTIME_INCLUDE_JARS")
    public String jars=null;

    @XmlElement(name="Class")
    public String classes;
}
```

Project `gert` `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gert</groupId>
    <artifactId>gert</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>gert.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory comes with this dependency-->
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Project `cristina` Class `Main`

```
package cristina;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory", "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
        String bWithDep = "C:\\Users\\gert\\eclipse-workspace91java\\gert\\target\\gert-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar";
        List<URL> jars = new java.util.ArrayList<URL>();
        File f;
        f = new File(bWithDep);
        jars.add(f.toURL());
        URL[] urls = (URL[])jars.toArray(new URL[jars.size()]);
        URLClassLoader urlloader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        System.out.println("Before\tgert.Main.test();.");
        Class<?> c= Class.forName("gert.Main", true, urlloader);
        Object gert = c.newInstance();
        Method m = c.getMethod("test");
        m.invoke(gert);
        System.out.println("After\tgert.Main.test();.");
    }
}
```

Project `cristina` `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cristina</groupId>
  <artifactId>cristina</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency> -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

So the cristina `main` loads the gert project and executes a method of gert named `test()`

### Testing

**Java 8**
When the project is run with java 8 it works

*Command*

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe" -cp C:\Users\gert\eclipse-workspace91java\cristina\target\cristina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar cristina.Main`

*Output*

`Before  gert.Main.test();.
After   gert.Main.test();.`
**Java 9**
When the same is done with java 9 it doesnt

*Command*

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\bin\java.exe" -cp C:\Users\gert\eclipse-workspace91java\cristina\target\cristina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar cristina.Main`

*Output*

```
Before  gert.Main.test();.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at cristina.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:397)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
        at gert.Main.test(Main.java:14)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
        ... 9 more
```

The 2 above are done directly from the command line.
**BUT**
When I uncomment the dependencies in the `pom.xml` of the `cristina` project and I do a maven install and **run the project from eclipse**, java 9 works. So it seems that eclipse also takes the maven dependencies into consideration when running a project.

### Question

When the dependencies are in the `gert` project and only used by the `gert` project why does the `cristina` project throw an exception when running it with Java 9?

Comment: If I read this correctly then you've got JAXB 2.3.0 API and the Eclipse implementation in cristina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, is that right? I don't know if this is relevant or not but when you use JDK 8 then you are using JAXB 2.2 included in the JDK. When you use JDK 9 then I assume it is loading the JAXB 2.3.0 API classes from your JAR file.

Comment: @AlanBateman to add to the detail about maven's behavior , the jar gert-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` has the `jaxb-api:2.3.0` and `jersey-media-moxy:2.26`, the dependencies in the `cristina` project are commented out.

Comment: Okay although I assume you see my point that the JAXB classes are not loaded from this JAR file when running on JDK 8. So the example is an upgrading from JAXB 2.2 to 2.3.0 and maybe there is an issue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the exception could probably be that [`java.xml.bind`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html) is an upgradeable module.

As the [JEP 261: Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) states in the Risks and assumptions for modules :

> If a package is defined in both a named module and on the class path
>   then the package on the class path will be ignored. The class path
>   can, therefore, no longer be used to augment packages that are built
>   into the environment.

Hence seems like the package `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb` is ignored. Eventually, the line of code `ContextFinder.newInstance` invokes the **[`JAXBContextFactory.createContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContextFactory.html#createContext-java.lang.Class:A-java.util.Map-)** with the classes provided to be bound(`ClassDef`). The documentation further states that

> throws `JAXBException` - if an error was encountered while creating the `JAXBContext`, such as (but not limited to) : ...
>
> - *classesToBeBound* are not open to `java.xml.bind` module

---

What you can try to do is while running the application make use of the

```
--upgrade-module-path /path/to/jaxb-api/dependency...
```

> A : separated list of directories, 
>     each directory is a directory of modules that 
>     replace upgradeable modules in the runtime image

Comment: This upgrade module path should point to the jar of the jersey-media-moxy dependency? If so, this doesn't work. `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\bin\java.exe" -cp C:\Users\gert\eclipse-workspace91java\cristina\target\cristina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar cristina.Main --upgrade-module-path C:\Users\gert\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-moxy\2.26\jersey-media-moxy-2.26.jar`

Comment: @GertKommer I thought the other jar shall be responsible for the jaxb-api, 
 `C:\Users\gert\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\2.3.0\`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the upgrade module path:) I now have `.\java.exe --upgrade-module-path "C:\Users\gert\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.moxy\2.7.0;C:\Users\gert\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.0;C:\Users\gert\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.core\2.7.0" --add-modules org.eclipse.persistence.moxy,org.eclipse.persistence.core,java.xml.bind -cp C:\Users\gert\eclipse-workspace91java\cristina\target\cristina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar cristina.Main` and this works for me in this particular case.